# PHPStorm can not open the Chrome?

Tags: php, google-chrome, phpstorm

I'm new to PHPStrom. Today i'm start the using PHPStrom. When i want to run php file on browsers using `Alt+F2` all browsers are opened normally.

But when i select Google Chrome , I got this error message.

Please help me , how to resolve this problem ?

[image]

Comment: This isn't a PHP related issue.. The program your using can't find chrome, it's as simple as that. Try reinstalling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Settings` | `Web Browsers` specify the correct path to Google Chrome on your system. Make sure it's installed and runs fine from the specified location:

[image: Web Browsers]